# Is it possible to define my own errors in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to define my own compile errors for Eclipse? I want to throw compile errors if certain objects are not instantiated.

To give you exactly what I want to do:

I have an `Assets` class that holds null variables for all resources (images, sounds, etc.) and a `LoadingScreen` class that initializes all of these resource objects. If I add a resource to the `Assets` class but not to the `LoadingScreen` class, it will mess up the whole application. I want to see an error in eclipse if the variables in the `Assets` class are not also initialized in `LoadingScreen`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this. You'll need to write an Eclipse plugin to do it. I'm not familiar with Eclipse development, but you will probably need to write a builder and may need to create a new facet as well. For a decently-sized project, it may be better to use Maven in any case and to implement this as a mojo.

Comment: Well, Eclipse does issue a warning if you forget to instantiate an object, but an error does happen at runtime. However, you can configure it to be an error. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm) to open Eclipse preferences, and configure "Null pointer access" to be an error.

Comment: I would not use Eclipse for this task, but try to use a source code analyzer as [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) or [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think your real problem (avoid to "mess up the whole application") should be solved at the Java level by adding preconditions and checks to avoid messed up state in your application.

Comment: What about passing all resources to the Assets class using a "parameter class" (e.g. InitialResources), which has private getters and a constructor having all required resources. You'll notice when you add a field and a getter to InitialResources, that you need to upgrade its constructor, then you'll have an error in class LoadingScreen.

Comment: Try throwable class of java to handle any user defined exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with LaurentG, I think you should solve this problem at Java level. For example, you could have a method which does at the end some final checks where you would check if any of your resources have a null pointer and throw a custom exception if you detect any.

```
if (resourceObject==null) {
throw new CustomException("Null pointer for resource object detected");
}

public class CustomException extends Exception {
   public CustomException (String errorMsg) {
   super(errorMsg);
  }
}
```

However, there are too many unknowns to give a really precise and accurate answer. Some code would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a new plugin or modify jdt.
The errors are detected when compiling using eclipse Batch compiler. You should take a look at [this](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup%22), and [this](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/problem).